# Meromorphic function at a point.

Tags: complex-analysis, branch-points, meromorphic-functions

i'm study meromorphic function at the complex plane extended, but i have a trouble. I know if $ f \colon D \subseteq \mathbb{C} \to \mathbb{C} $  $f$ is meromorphic on D if the singularities of $f$ are poles in $D$
But whats mean $f$ is meromorphic at a point $a \in \mathbb {C}$?

Other quickly question, anyone knows why $\infty$ is branched point of $log(z) $?

Thanks

Comment: In answer to your second question:  $\infty$ is a branch point of $\log z$ because $0$ is a branch point of $\log \frac{1}{z} = -\log z$.

Comment: We usually don't define holomorphicity, meromorphicity, etc. at single points because singletons are closed and we need open sets for almost all the nice theorems. I would thus assume that when someone writes that "$f$ is meromorphic at $a$" the author is saying "$f$ is meromorphic in a neighborhood of $a$". However, without knowing the context you found this it is hard to say

Comment: I've found this in "Complex functions: An algebraic and geometric viewpoint" - Singerman. The point of this is extend the notions of analytic and meromorphic functions at complex plane extend,  autor says $f(z) $ are analytic, meromorphic, etc... at infinity if $f(1/z)$ are analytic, meromorphic, etc... At $0$.

Comment: @DavisWe Oh, then yes - the author means analytic in a neighborhood. This is very standard terminology. You are essentially looking at some small neighborhood of the north pole on the Riemann sphere and seeing if you get holo/mero-morphicity. (For some sort of reference, [here's a post on this site](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/484334/are-there-two-conventional-definitions-of-holomorphic) from a quick google search. Let me know if you still have questions on this)